# How to suppress the "Stage 2===>" from the output console in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have dataframe and trying to get distinct count and able to get distinct count successfully but whenever scala program is executing i'm getting this message `([Stage 2:=============================>                             (1 + 1) / 2])`how can i suppress particular this message in console.

```
val countID = dataDF.select(substring(col("dataDF"),5,7).distinct().count()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set `spark.ui.showConsoleProgress` to `false`

I found this in the comments of the ticket for the addition of the progress bar.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4017

I haven't seen it in any of the documentation though, it really should be added.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it by code. Add the following when you are creating the SparkContext:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)  // Disabling "INFO" level logs (these lines must be before to create the SparkContext)
val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.ui.showConsoleProgress", "false").setAppName("myApp")  
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

***UPDATE CONTENT FOR SPARK2+:***

Using SparkSession you can supress those messages adding the following line (`.config("spark.ui.showConsoleProgress", "false")`) to the declaration:

```
spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("myApp")
      .config("spark.ui.showConsoleProgress", "false")
```