# Spark-shell not allowing to query the structured stream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am following the book **Spark the Definitive Guide**
The following code is executed locally using spark-shell

Procedure:
Started the spark-shell without any other options

```scala
val static = spark.read.json("/part-00079-tid-730451297822678341-1dda7027-2071-4d73-a0e2-7fb6a91e1d1f-0-c000.json")
val dataSchema = static.schema
val streaming = spark.readStream.schema(dataSchema) .option("maxFilesPerTrigger",1).json("/part-00079-tid-730451297822678341-1dda7027-2071-4d73-a0e2-7fb6a91e1d1f-0-c000.json")
val activityCounts = streaming.groupBy("gt").count()
val activityQuery  = activityCounts.writeStream.queryName("activity_counts").format("memory").outputMode("complete").start()
activityQuery.awaitTermination()
```

The Books says that

> After this code is executed the streaming computation will have started in the background
>
> ....
>
> Now that this stream is running , we can experiment with the result by querying

**My observation**:

When this code is executed it does not frees the shell for me to type in the commands 
such as

```
`spark.streams.active`
```

Hence I cannot query this stream

**My resarch**

I tried to open a new spark-shell but querying in that shell does not returns any results. Are the streams obtained from this shell accessible from other another instance of the shell.

**EDIT1 :**

I want the table in memory so that I can use the to query using command

```
for( i <- 1 to 5)
{
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM activity_counts").show()
Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Couple of points:

1) Make sure the enough number of Cores are allocated to Spark-shell

Atleast 2 cores are required to run the Streaming / Structured Streaming application to prevent a **Starvation Scenario** i.e when the streaming app is launched 1 core will be allocated to **Receiver** and if you launch spark application with only 1 core, there will be no cores available to process the received messages for executors.

To check the number of cores in spark-shell:

```
spark.conf.get("spark.master")
```

To launch spark-shell with 4 cores

```
spark-shell --master local[4]
```

2) You are writing the stream to Memory, this will not display the output in the console, to display you have to register the table and then query.

Instead you can change the format from **memory** to **console** to view the contents in console.

```
val activityQuery  = activityCounts.writeStream.queryName("activity_counts").format("console").outputMode("complete").start()
```

Comment: spark.conf.get("spark.master") produced output local[*]. 
Anyways I started the shell using the command given by you and changed from memory to console. It worked  fine i.e showing on console but I wanted it in memory and still the console is not free so that I can write my own statements like spark.streams.active.

Comment: I understand that this has started the streaming but should'nt the shell be free for me to type commands ? I want to free the shell to allow me type the following command  
see EDIT1

Comment: awaitTermination() is to prevent the process from exiting while the query is active. In Spark Shell, we don't need to execute this, because the driver will be active until we close the shell.

Comment: You can directly query "activity_counts" table after you executed activityQuery

Comment: But then it cannot be called "streaming" is'nt it??if I have to wait to execute my query then does'nt that makes it a batch processing ? Whereas the book says otherwise. It says and I quote ----> " to see the data in this output table we simply need to query it!! We'll do do  this in a simple loop that will print the results of the streaming query every second" with the loop being the one I have mentioned in the EDIT1

Comment: The file will be processed and updated to memory as and when it receives the file. You can see the file processing progress in console. Only to query from the Memory you need to execute that query.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is really late, you would have already found it by now, giving just in case someone else asks this question now:

You need to start the spark shell with **spark.ui.showConsoleProgress=false**

```
spark-shell --conf spark.ui.showConsoleProgress=false
```

and as mentioned by [Lakshman Battini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8085047/lakshman-battini)

> change the format from **memory** to **console** to view the contents in
> console

to know more about this, you can see the question:

[How to suppress the “Stage 2===>” from the output console in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420250/how-to-suppress-the-stage-2-from-the-output-console-in-spark)

[puhlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5638835/puhlen) has given perfect answer for this.

For more info on Console Progress Bar visit this [link](https://mallikarjuna_g.gitbooks.io/spark/spark-sparkcontext-ConsoleProgressBar.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Spark shell just avoid `activityQuery.awaitTermination()`. The stream has been already started with `.start()`.

You will also be available to stop stream by `activityQuery.stop()`

Comment: Yes you are right with awaittermination() but the cursor does not return to the shell for me to type the new commands which is given in EDIT1

Comment: Just hit Enter, and shell give you control.